# Wrapped alphabet numbering

Tags: html, css

Hi I like to use ordered list like this.

```
      (a) You must give any other recipients of the Work or
          Derivative Works a copy of this License; and

      (b) You must cause any modified files to carry prominent notices
          stating that You changed the files; and

      (c) You must retain, in the Source form of any Derivative Works
          that You distribute, all copyright, patent, trademark, and
          attribution notices from the Source form of the Work,
          excluding those notices that do not pertain to any part of
          the Derivative Works; and

      (d) If the Work includes a "NOTICE" text file as part of its
          distribution, then any Derivative Works that You distribute must
```

I tried this but it shows the numbers.

```
/* Wrap alphabet. */
ol.wrapAlphabet {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
    counter-reset: item;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

ol.wrapAlphabet li {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 2em;
}

ol.wrapAlphabet li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "(" counter(item) ") ";
    counter-increment: item;
    width: 2em;
    margin-left: -2em;
}​
```

Html

```
<ol class="wrapAlphabet">
<li>
      You must give any other recipients of the Work or
          Derivative Works a copy of this License; and
</li>

<li>
      You must cause any modified files to carry prominent notices
          stating that You changed the files; and
</li>

<li>
      You must retain, in the Source form of any Derivative Works
          that You distribute, all copyright, patent, trademark, and
          attribution notices from the Source form of the Work,
          excluding those notices that do not pertain to any part of
          the Derivative Works; and
</li>
```

Comment: You could have put the HTML too for ease! :)

Comment: Well the HTML is easy to figure out, something as <ol class="wrapAlphabet">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ol> works.

Comment: Lolz, that's what I did.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `content: "("counter(item, lower-alpha)")";` instead of `content: "(" counter(item) ") ";` should work

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J5NmV/1/

Answer (score 1):

The `counter(item)` gives you only integers instead of number. So, you need to use JavaScript or jQuery to loop in through and set an attribute, say `data-count` and set the alphabets.

Then you need to replace the `counter(item)` to `attr(data-count)` so that it displays alphabets.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use this CSS:

```
/* Wrap alphabet. */
ol.wrapAlphabet {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
    counter-reset: item;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

ol.wrapAlphabet li {
}

ol.wrapAlphabet li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "(";
    counter-increment: item;
    width: 2em;
    margin-left: -1.75em;
}
ol.wrapAlphabet li:after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: ")";
    counter-increment: item;
    width: 2em;
    margin-left: -3.5em;
}
​
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x5Rwv/

---

#### If you are using a better modern browser (I assume), you can simply replace:

```
content: "("counter(item)";
```

With:

```
content: "("counter(item, lower-alpha)")";
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x5Rwv/1/